# Filter the Big String

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of String and the task is to find out the longest string in the array and the location of that string.I am wondering if I can convert the array to list and by using stream I can solve the same problem. Any help would be appreciated

I've already solved the problem using traditional way, using loops and some if conditions

```
String names[]={"John","Malisa","Stack Overflow"};

String b=names[i];
int max=b.length();

for(int i=1;i<names.length;i++) {
    if(max<names[i].length) {
        max=names[i].length;
        b=names[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to change it to a list. Use `Arrays.stream` to stream the contents of an array. Also, your solution is not giving the location of the max string, and a stream will make it more difficult to find that (though not impossible).

Comment: and how do I us the filter method with stream, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `filter` method to find the longest string in array. Use [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) with comparator:

```
String max = Arrays.stream(names)
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
        .orElse("");
```

To find the index of this element use:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(max);
```

Comment: what about max in the indexOf?

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `Arrays.stream` and compare length:

```
    String names[]={"John","Malisa","Stack Overflow"};
    Optional<String> max = Arrays.stream(names)
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    System.out.println(max.orElse("none"));
```

**UPD**
I didn't understand your question correctly.
You can use this code to get index of max element:

```
    String names[]={"John","Malisa","Stack Overflow"};

    int index = IntStream.range(0, names.length)
            .reduce((i, j) -> names[i].length() > names[j].length() ? i : j)
            .getAsInt();

    System.out.println(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :-

```
Arrays.stream(names)
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length,Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .findFirst()
       .get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach for getting the longest string and its index at the same time:

```
String[] names = {"John", "Malisa", "Stack Overflow"};
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, names.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> names[i], Function.identity()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey().length()));

result.ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Longest String: '" + e.getKey() + "' at index " + e.getValue()));
```

This creates a map with the string and its index. After that it returns the entry with the longest string.

The result for your `names` array is:

```
Longest String: 'Stack Overflow' at index 2
```